# MongoDB random document with WHERE statement

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new to MongoDB and I have a problem.
I want to select a random document but with a condition.
In SQL I would have done something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM challenges
WHERE level = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Now I need to do this in MongoDB, but I only get to the point where I select a random value

```
Challenge.aggregate({
        $sample: {size:1}
},
```

How can I add an WHERE statement, I've only seen it with challenge.find, but I'm already aggregating.

Any help would be highly appriciated.

Comment: aggregate have `$match` clause. That's your WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Challenge.aggregate([
 {
   $match:{
     field1: condition1,
     field2: condition2
   }
 },
 {
    $sample: {size:1}
 }
])
```